# c++ how to delete a class via pointer to the class

Tags: c++, pointers

Somewhere in my code I call: `A* p = new A;` and I put the pointer p in a vector.

Now I want to delete the pointer and the class the pointer is pointing to. 
like this:

```
A* p = getpointerfromvector(index); // gets the correct pointer
```

Delete the pointer from the vector:

```
vector.erase(vector.begin()+index)
```

Now I want to delete the class the pointer is pointing to and delete it.

```
delete p; // (doest work: memorydump)
```

or `p->~A` with `~A` the destructor of class A with body: `delete this;`. (my program quits whenever I call the function.)

Comment: A small clarification on nomenclature: In your case `A` is the name of a class, while `p` is a pointer to an object. When you do `new A` you are creating a new *object*, not a new *class*. It is important to keep the notions of class and object separate :)

Comment: Please show a complete, compilable example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: `delete p` is correct. If it doesn't work, post an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I bet you have wrong index.

Comment: if I call delete p: i get a memorydump and my program quits

Comment: @SergeSeredenko If I don't call delete p my program compiles fine, works fine. But when I call new A, I must delete it furthor on in my program to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: Yes, you said that in your question. Which is why we asked to see the rest of your code, because calling `delete p;` is the correct thing to do if the thing pointed to by `p` was allocated with `new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me. Cant compare it to your code since its not all in your post.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

class A
{
public:
    A() {mNum=0; printf("A::A()\n");}
    A(int num) {mNum = num; printf("A::A()\n");}
    ~A() {printf("A::~A() - mNum = %d\n", mNum);}
private:
    int mNum;
};

int main ()
{
    A *p;
    vector <A*> aVec;
    int i, n=10;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        p = new A(i);
        aVec.push_back(p);
    }
    int index = 4;
    p = aVec[index];
    aVec.erase(aVec.begin()+index);
    delete(p);
}
```

**Output:**

```
A::A()
A::A()
A::A()
A::A()
A::A()
A::A()
A::A()
A::A()
A::A()
A::A()
A::~A() - mNum = 4
```

Comment: I forgot to change my destructor to ~A{} instead of ~A{delete this}

Comment: Easily done. It's for just these kinds of oversights, that you should always aim to post an SSCCE - Short Self Contained Correct (Compilable) Example. (http://www.sscce.org/)